# Settext Method of Textview

Tags: android, textview

I am working on implementing a stopwatch by using a Chronometer and a Textview. The problem i am facing is that the Settext method refreshes the UI which disturbs the offsettopandbottom method i am using for animation on my ListView.

Is there any way that the Settext method only refreshes the Textview or does not disturb my Listview.

Code for the chronometer

```
        stopwatch.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {

            int countup = (int) ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - arg0
                    .getBase()) / 1000);
            String asText = (countup / 60) + ":" + (countup % 60);
            tvtimer.setText("Time Elapsed :- " + asText);
        }
```

Comment: Please, share relevant layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

Create a handler and use that as to set your TextView's text.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String message = (String) msg.obj.toString();

            // Set your UI mods here
            tvtimer.setText("Time Elapsed :- " + message);

            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };
```

// Then in your TickListener, do this:

```
stopwatch.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {

        int countup = (int) ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - arg0
                .getBase()) / 1000);
        String asText = (countup / 60) + ":" + (countup % 60);

        // Send a message to your handler
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.obj = asText;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);

    }
```

Hope it helps :)